# Attributed UILabel does not respect IB

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

For the first time i decided to use NSAttributed string  for my UILabel,

nevertheless when i set my UILabel attributes (font, color, alignement) of my labels in IB (interface builder interface) when i run my code the attributes are never respected ! I have to manually add attributes to my labels :

```
_myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:25];
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is applying a font font the text property of the label. If you'd like to assign a font for attributed text, you have to assign that font as one of the attributed string's attributes.

```
NSString *inputString = @"fsdfdsf";

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:25]};

NSAttributedString *attributecString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:inputString attributes:attributes];

[_myLabel setAttributedText:attributecString];
```

Comment: That is waht i do but my IB attributes are not respected so i set them in the code . . .

Comment: @JackoJack If you set attributed text to the label, the previous attributes will be lost. You have to reapplied attributes to the string.

Comment: thanks ! so i have to set attributed text to label in IB and use .text in my code ?

Comment: @JackoJack No, you set _lable.attributedText wherever you'd like, you just have to make sure that you apply the same attributes to the new string that you're applying.